# for_each loop cannot access a new merged local var in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'vebeen trying to merge two separate variables into one varriable to access them both in one for_each loop (like getting app and acl answers in the same loop) so I did it using

```
locals {
  merged_vars = merge(var.apps, var.acl)
}
```

now I need to apply a for_each loop in the code but var are not accessing as it should be
a piece of the new resource code I've made:

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "acl" {
  for_each = var.merged_vars
  metadata {
    name      = "${each.value.labels.name}-pod"
    namespace = each.value.app_name
  }

  spec {
    policy_types = ["Ingress", "Egress"]
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {
        tier = each.value.labels.tier
      }
    }
    ingress {
      from {
        namespace_selector {
          match_labels = {
            name = each.value.ingress
          }
        }
      }
      ports {
        port     = each.value.acl.port
        protocol = each.value.acl.protocol
      }
    }
    egress {
      to {
        ip_block {
          cidr = each.value.acl.egress
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Old resource (before merging looked like) and was with 3 resource for app1\2\3 and I've wanted to make a for loop to make it as 1 resource instead of 3:

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "app1" {
  metadata {
    name      = format("%s-acl", var.app1_name)
    namespace = var.app1_name
  }
  spec {
    policy_types = ["Ingress", "Egress"]
    pod_selector {
      match_labels = {
        tier = "web"
      }
    }
```

the error I am receiving after trying :

```
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on network.tf line 13, in resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "acl":
│   13:     namespace = each.value.app_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 5 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "app_name".
```

### I will give you a quick view on what my vars are so you will have a bit of understanding:

var resources are:

```
variable "apps" {
  type = map(object({
    app_name    = string
    labels      = map(string)
    annotations = map(string)
    image       = string
  }))
  default = {
    "app1_name" = {
      app_name = "app1_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer_and_class" = "external"
      }
      image = "nxinx"
    }
    "app2_name" = {
      app_name = "app2_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-frontend"
        "tier"  = "web"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "web-frontend"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "external"
      }
      image = "nginx"
    }

    "app3_name" = {
      app_name = "app3_name"

      labels = {
        "name"  = "stream-database"
        "tier"  = "shared"
        "owner" = "product"
      }

      annotations = {
        "serviceClass"       = "disabled"
        "loadBalancer/class" = "disabled"
      }
      image = "Mongo"
    }
  }
}

variable "acl" {
  type = map(object({
    acl_name = string
    ingress  = string
    egress   = string
    port     = string
    protocol = string
  }))
  default = {
    "frontend" = {

      acl_name = "acl_frontend"
      ingress  = "stream-frontend"
      egress   = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port     = "80"
      protocol = "TCP"

    },
    "backend" = {

      acl_name   = "acl_backend"
      ingress    = "stream-backend"
      egress     = "0.0.0.0/0"
      port       = "80"
      "protocol" = "TCP"
    },
    "database" = {

      acl_name   = "acl_database"
      "ingress"  = "stream-database"
      "egress"   = "172.17.0.0/24"
      "port"     = "27017"
      "protocol" = "TCP"
    }
  }
}
```

```
 thank you for your answers!
-----------------couple of things i've tried------------------

have been trying to put
```

`each.value.app_name`

even just as

`each.value.apps`

or even as

`each.value.merged_vars`

but the error is the same to all of these
an exaple of the error again using the letter "X"
"each.value is object with X attributes,  This object does not have an attribute named "X".

Comment: Please add the entire resource block for ACL to the question.

Comment: I've edited the whole question and put the whole variable.tf resource :)

Comment: basically i wanted to merge var "apps" and var "acl" so i could for_each them both on network.tf 
each.value.(var app or acl).(the attribute i need such as in apps migh be app_name or in acl could be port) 
but when I've merged them in local as I was suggested it does not pull the attribute as you see above

Comment: could you also please share the entire resource blocks , i really belive there should be a simple way of doing things here such has using dynamic block or cross resource referencing.

Comment: It does not work because you have two different variables with different types and values and when you merge them into one its not a consistent value. "each.value.app_name" exists in var. apps but not in var.acl, and because you merge both variables together, it has to loop over entirely new local.merge_vars and inconsistent [ could not find each.value.app_name]
In your error message

Comment: I've updated the code, 
and I'm trying to make 3 resources for app1\2\3 in to one resource the will be called "app" 
and let it loop to get attribues.
is there a better way to make it work? 
as I understood ot was for_each loop and merge in local but I was mistaken as you explained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two variables have incompatible object types, and so merging them together creates a very object value where some of the attributes are shaped like application and others are shaped like ACLs.

Those two object types have no attribute names in common, so there isn't really anything useful you can do with that merged value: if you access `each.value.app_name` then it will fail for the objects that are ACLs, and if you access `each.value.acl_name` then it will fail for all of the objects that are apps.

If you want to use all of these values together in the same way you'll need to first convert them all to a common object type that somehow makes sense for both kinds of source object. I'm not sure what "apps" and "ACLs" have in common so I can't guess what might make sense here but for the sake of example I'll focus on just the `app_name` and `acl_name` arguments, converting both sets of objects into a new object type that just has an attribute `name` that's common across all of them:

```
locals {
  merged = tomap(merge(
    {
      for k, v in var.apps : k => {
        name = v.app_name
      }
    },
    {
      for k, v in var.acls : k => {
        name = v.acl_name
      }
    },
  ))
}
```

With the default values shown in your `variable` blocks, the value of `local.merged` would then be:

```
tomap({
  app1_name = {
    name = "app1_name"
  }
  app2_name = {
    name = "app2_name"
  }
  app3_name = {
    name = "app3_name"
  }
  frontend = {
    name = "acl_frontend"
  }
  backend = {
    name = "acl_backend"
  }
  database = {
    name = "acl_database"
  }
})
```

These elements are now all of the same type (`object({name = string})`) so this map is now useful to use with `for_each`, as long as the name is all you need from each object:

```
resource "kubernetes_network_policy" "example" {
  for_each = local.merged

  metadata {
    name      = format("%s-acl", each.value.name)
    namespace = each.value.name
  }
  spec {
    # ...
  }
}
```

You probably need more than just `name` in each of these objects, in which case you should expand the result expressions in my definition of `local.merged` above to include whatever extra attributes you need.

You will need to decide for each extra attribute you add how to populate it from both the apps object type and for the acls object type. If you have some attributes that only make sense for one or the other then you could set them to `null` or some other empty value in the situations where they aren't needed so that the resulting objects will still be all of the same type:

```
locals {
  merged = tomap(merge(
    {
      for k, v in var.apps : k => {
        name     = v.app_name
        labels   = v.labels
        protocol = tostring(null)
      }
    },
    {
      for k, v in var.acls : k => {
        name     = v.acl_name
        labels   = tomap({})
        protocol = v.protocol
      }
    },
  ))
}
```

With the above example the resulting objects will all be of the following type, but some of them will have `protocol` set to a null string, and some will have `labels` set to an empty map:

```
map(object({
  name     = string
  labels   = map(string)
  protocol = string
}))
```

When you write the expressions in your `resource` block you'll now need to consider how to handle the empty labels or null protocol. Assigning a null value to a resource argument is exactly equivalent to not setting that argument at all, so you may be able to just unconditionally assign `each.value.protocol` to an argument and let the provider understand the `null` values as that argument not being set.